# Feature activation running slowly on one environment

Tags: feature, feature-activation, feature-receiver

We have 3 farms, Dev, QA, and Production.  Feature activations are running very slowly on the QA environment only. I  have a custom feature that deploys files out to the style library and changes the MasterPage.  It times out before activating.  This same feature takes about 5 seconds in the other environments.  Even the 'SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features' feature took nearly 40 seconds to activate on the QA environment.  The environment was working fine until recently.  Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: No hints in the event log, ULS, or Health Analyzer.

Comment: did you check, if SharePoint Admin job is running and also timer? can server access to internet? also check if CPU or memory goes high during?

Comment: All SharePoint services are running, all servers can hit the internet, and the resources on the server look great.  I'm suspicious that it is a SQL issue but I don't have access to the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL was incorrectly configured.  Since I had no insight or permissions on the SQL server it was difficult to pin the issues on SQL.  Once SQL was reconfigured, the issues disappeared.  I did not reconfigure SQL and thus do not know specifically what was wrong.